# Need help tuning query - left join using concatenated fields not efficient

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I've written a query where I'm filtering out records from a population where values of 2 fields in a nested query are equal to 2 corresponding fields in a table. I'm trying to use the concatenation of the 2 key fields as a lookup.

While this does get me the results I'm looking for it seems that this method is pretty inefficient as the query takes around 60 seconds to return results (the `CRM.ASSET_PLUS` table has over 10M records). Assuming I can't filter anything out and without creating a custom field in `CRM.ASSET_PLUS` with those 2 fields already concatenated.

Is there a better way I can being doing this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
  FROM (SELECT C.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
               A.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID || A.PRODUCT_ID AS LOOKUP
          FROM CRM.ASSET_PLUS A,
               CRM.PROD_INT B,
               CRM.ACCOUNT C,
               CRM.ACCOUNT D
         WHERE A.PRODUCT_ID = B.ROW_ID
           AND A.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID = C.ACCOUNT_ID
           AND C.PARENT_ID = D.ACCOUNT_ID
           AND D.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = '00750333'
       ) A
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT A.LOCATION_ACCT_ID || A.PRODUCT_ID AS LOOKUP
                FROM ORDER_FORM_PRODUCTS A
               WHERE A.AGREEMENT_NUM = '00750333_JUN2014'
             ) B
     ON A.LOOKUP = B.LOOKUP
  WHERE B.LOOKUP IS NULL;
```

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN(SELECT ...) B WHERE B.xxx IS NULL` IS equivalent to a `NOT EXISTS(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of concatenating try joining on multiple fields

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
FROM 
    CRM.ASSET_PLUS A,
    CRM.PROD_INT B,
    CRM.ACCOUNT C,
    CRM.ACCOUNT D
LEFT JOIN ORDER_FORM_PRODUCTS E 
    ON (E.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID = A.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID
       OR (E.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID IS NULL AND A.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID IS NULL))
    AND (E.PRODUCT_ID = A.PRODUCT_ID 
        OR (E.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL AND A.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL))
    AND E.AGREEMENT_NUM = '00750333_JUN2014'
WHERE 
    A.PRODUCT_ID = B.ROW_ID 
    AND A.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID = C.ACCOUNT_ID
    AND C.PARENT_ID = D.ACCOUNT_ID
    AND D.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = '00750333'
    AND E.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID IS NULL
    AND E.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL
```

For clarity I recommend making your joins explicit

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
FROM 
    CRM.ASSET_PLUS A
    JOIN CRM.PROD_INT B ON A.PRODUCT_ID = B.ROW_ID
    JOIN CRM.ACCOUNT C ON A.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID = C.ACCOUNT_ID
    JOIN CRM.ACCOUNT D ON C.PARENT_ID = D.ACCOUNT_ID
        AND D.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = '00750333'
    LEFT JOIN ORDER_FORM_PRODUCTS E 
       ON (E.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID = A.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID
         OR (E.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID IS NULL AND A.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID IS NULL))
       AND (E.PRODUCT_ID = A.PRODUCT_ID 
         OR (E.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL AND A.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL))
       AND E.AGREEMENT_NUM = '00750333_JUN2014'
WHERE 
    E.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID IS NULL
    AND E.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the same results. Records where E.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID is not null and E.PRODUCT_ID is null get filtered out (and vice versa). I need only records where both E.PRODUCT_ID and E.LOCATION_ACCOUNT_ID are null to be filtered.

Comment: @StephenT updated to join using `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`

Comment: @StephenT i'm actually not sure if oracle allows `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` so I replaced that with joining on `NULL` in an `OR`